# Match space between chars except start of line

Tags: python, regex

I have a substitution in Python which looks like this :

```
re.sub('','?',"Man")
```

The only problem is that the output is :

```
?M?a?n?
```

But I want to avoid the first substitution so it looks like this :

```
M?a?n?
```

How can I avoid matching only the start of the line but keep matching everything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you must use regex, you could use a negative look-ahead assertion:

```
re.sub(r'(?!^)', '?', "Man")
# Yields "M?a?n?"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay not using regex. Not exactly the way you want but will still do the job

```
'?'.join("Man")+'?'
```

Comment: This is okay as a workaround if I don't get it the way I want to do it. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't yield what the OP wants. It will yield "M?a?n" (no trailing question mark).